# SocksJS / Stomp / Spring websocket MissingSessionUserException: No “user” header in message

Tags: angularjs, spring, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket

I need to react on a user destination subscription.

Example:

A user subscribes to /user/api/notifications, because they want to receive all incoming notifications. Now I'd like to look up any notifications for this user, which were created while he was offline, and then send them to that user.

Client via AngularJS:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app.services').service('socketService', ['$rootScope', '$stomp', 'storageService', 'storageConstant', 'propertiesConstant',
function socketService($rootScope, $stomp, storageService, storageConstant, propertiesConstant) {
    var connection;
    var subscriptions = {};

    this.subscribe = function subscribe() {
        var authToken = storageService.getSessionItem(storageConstant.AUTH_TOKEN);
        var headers = (authToken) ? {"X-AUTH-TOKEN": authToken} : {};

        connect(headers);

        connection.then(function (frame) {
            if (!(subscriptions.notifications)) {
                subscriptions.notifications = $stomp.subscribe('/user/api/notifications', function (payload, headers, res) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        $rootScope.notificationCount = payload.length;
                    })
                }, headers);
            }
        });
    };

    this.unsubscribe = function unsubscribe() {
        if (subscriptions.notifications) {
            subscriptions.notifications.unsubscribe();
        }

        if (connection) {
            $stomp.disconnect(function () {
                delete $rootScope.notificationCount;
            });

            connection = null;
        }

        subscriptions = {};
    };

    function connect(headers) {
        if (!(connection)) {
            connection = $stomp.connect(propertiesConstant.WEBSOCKET_API_URL + '/stomp', headers);
        }
    }
}]);
```

API via Spring 4:

Controller Endpoint:

```
@SubscribeMapping("/api/notifications")
    public List<NotificationDetail> notifications(Principal p) {
        String user = p.getName();

        LOG.info("User is {}", user);

        return notificationService.getNotifications(AuthenticationUtil.getUsername());
    }
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        super.configureMessageBroker(registry);

        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app", "/user");
        registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/stomp").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

Exception I receive on the API:

```
2016-05-26 13:06:59,766 ERROR  - Unhandled exception
org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.MissingSessionUserException: No "user" header in message
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.PrincipalMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PrincipalMethodArgumentResolver.java:42)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:98)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:107)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:490)
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.java:497)
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.java:87)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:451)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:389)
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$SendTask.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:135)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What have I missed / done wrong?

Thank you :)

Comment: as far as i know when you use `setUserDestination` you are specifying the user prefix; this means that the broker tries to search for a user dedicated topic/queue; try to avoid to use `setUserDestination` but use `enableSimpleBroker`